# I can't find file `tikzlibraryarrows.spaced.code.tex'. \usetikzlibrary{arrows.spaced}

Tags: tikz-arrows

I have received a Tex document which I am trying to compile, and I keep getting the error

```
I can't find file `tikzlibraryarrows.spaced.code.tex'. \usetikzlibrary{arrows.spaced}
```

The document preamble ***contains*** :

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.spaced}
```

Does anyone know how can I solve this? Is it a package which i have to install?
I am using Miktex on a Windows7 Machine.

---

Following the comments from @HarishKumar and @Zarko, I tried to install missing packages (although my Miktex is configured to install missing packages on the fly). Here is a screen shot of it now:
[image]

After installation, I tried to update using the `update(Admin)` and there were no updates available, and the error message is still the same!

Comment: From manual (page 182): `Remark: The libraries arrows and arrows.spaced are deprecated. Use arrows.meta instead/addition-
ally, which allows you to do all that the old libraries offered, plus much more. However, the old libraries
still work and you can even mix old and new arrow tips (only, the old arrow tips cannot be configured in
the ways described in the rest of this section; saying scale=2 for a latex arrow has no effect for instance,
while for Latex arrows it doubles their size as one would expect.)`

Comment: @HarishKumar : I already tried that and i get `I can't find file \`tikzlibraryarrows.meta.code.tex'. \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}`

Comment: Then you may still be using version 2.10. Try to upgrade your tikz. Latest is version 3.

Comment: @user2536125, which TikZ you have installed? Recent version is 3.0.1, it contain libraries `arrows.meta`.

Comment: @HarishKumar and @Zarko I have set Miktex to install packages on the fly. When I check using the `Miktex Package Manager`there are 22 package all starting with ***tikz***. Which one do I have to check?

Comment: @user2536125, all :-)

Comment: @Zarko , please check my post update.

Comment: Install on the fly is *not* the same as keeping your LaTeX installation up to date.

Comment: @user2536125, oh miss understanding. I thing that you will update your MikTeX instalation. For it use  tools `update` (with administration rights, if necessary). For recent TukZ you need to have recent `pgf` package. It contain `TikZ` with all library of Till Tantau team. Under `TikZ`-key in `Package manager` you will find set of TikZ derivatives like `ciruitikz` (which I use frequently) and many others. For your question no one of them is needed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was solved after updating the LaTeX system.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina : I removed all my texlive and texmf and pgfplots installations and installed the latest from scratch (in Ubuntu 14.04.  I still get the same error. I installed the latest pgf package as well.  There might be something else. I tried my TEXINPUTS path and it looks fine. I just can not locate the file   tikzlibraryarrows.meta.code.tex  on the system. Where should that file be located?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just managed to solve the problem by updating as an `admin` and as a `normal user`. I was doing it before only as Admin and this wasn't anough.